# PostScript error with imagemask and raw data

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

In Adobe's [PLRM](https://www.adobe.com/products/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf)
I found the following example using the `imagemask` operator.
This works fine when running with Ghostscript.

```
54 112 translate               % Locate lower-left corner of square
120 120 scale                  % Scale 1 unit to 120 points
0 setgray                      % Set current color to black
24 23                          % Specify dimensions of source mask
true                           % Set polarity to paint the 1 bits
[24 0 0 -23 0 23]              % Map unit square to mask
{< 003B00 002700 002480 0E4940
   114920 14B220 3CB650 75FE88
   17FF8C 175F14 1C07E2 3803C4
   703182 F8EDFC B2BBC2 BB6F84
   31BFC2 18EA3C 0E3E00 07FC00
   03F800 1E1800 1FF800 >}
imagemask
showpage
```

As an exercise I tried to rewrite the above example using an ImageType-1 dictionary and raw data, and finally came up with this code:

```
54 112 translate
120 120 scale
0 setgray
<<
  /ImageType 1
  /Width 24
  /Heigth 23
  /BitsPerComponent 1
  /Decode [1 0]
  /ImageMatrix [24 0 0 -23 0 23]
  /DataSource currentfile /ASCIIHexDecode filter
>>
imagemask
003B00 002700 002480 0E4940
114920 14B220 3CB650 75FE88
17FF8C 175F14 1C07E2 3803C4
703182 F8EDFC B2BBC2 BB6F84
31BFC2 18EA3C 0E3E00 07FC00
03F800 1E1800 1FF800>
showpage
```

However, when running this with Ghostscript I get the following error.

```
Error: /undefined in --imagemask--
```

I'm still scratching my head to find the bug, but in vain.
How can it be `imagemask` is undefined? Or did I miss something obvious?

Comment: One clue from the error message is the `--`...`--` around `imagemask`. The hyphens mean that this is the imagemask *operator* that hit an undefined error (*inside* the operator). If it was just the bare name, like `Error: /undefined in imagemask` that would mean the name was not defined.

Comment: @luserdroog   ok, so it was the `imagemask` operator hitting `/undefined` error because `Height` was undefined in the dictionary.

Comment: One advantage of the older *proc* forms of `image ` and `imagemask` is that you can swap the call with `exec` to debug the proc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is **exactly** the code you've written, but there's a typo:

```
  /Heigth 23
```

which should obviously be:

```
  /Height 23
```

If I correct that, the file runs to completion, and draws the turkey.